# is "shastric evidence" acceptable for events that allegedly happened after India developed a historical tradition?

Tags: history

the date of sankaracharya is given variously and it is said that a kapalika tried to sacrifice him.  but these were times when more historically oriented religions were on the scene- buddhism, Jainism islam and Christianity as well as travelers such as Marco Polo, al beruni and so forth.  Wiki says that evidence about Kapalikas is available from fictional works and other traditions who disparage them.

we need to adhere to verifiable truth as far as possible.

Comment: What Shastric evidences? The Q is not quite clear to me.. Biographies of a scholar are not  Shastric evidences to start with

Comment: sankaracharya himself is semi-legendary.  it is asserted that some kapalika wanted to sacrifice him - and a layer of fantasy is added on top that the man-lion saved him.  if secular research shows there is no evidence of kapalikas having conducted human sacrifice either during sankara's time or at any time, then whatever is asserted in sankara's biography about this has to be rejected. @rickross

Comment: @Rickross Shastaric evidence is *shabda pramana*. Puranas, Itihasas, Vedas, etc.

Comment: Yeah I  know .. @Ikshvaku